# avoid html element getting out of place when window is narrow

Tags: html, css

This is a very simple question for others but i want to get idea on what to do on my html.. I have a simple html with images div tables and paragraphs..It is working ok on regular screen when the window is not adjusted to small window..After coding half of the index i tried making the window small and i saw a big problem my website is scattered all the images div tables are everywhere..Question is how do i avoid this problem?hopefully using css only..I tried google but there is no exact answer for this question..

Comment: [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: Do you want something similar to StackOverflow _

Comment: @LarsNielsen yes as long as the elements inside it doesnt scatter like what is happening now...or maybe i can have a div that stays when the screen is small and the others disappear i need idea on how to make it happen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about **[Responsive Website](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)** designing. Here are few good resources to start with.

- [Responsive Web Design Basics](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/)
- [HTML5 - Responsive Web Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx)
- [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
- [Media Queries - Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Or better star developing websites with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Comment: i had trouble researching for the term so it is a reponsive website thank you sir for the idea...

Comment: Yup this is the term. If you work on Word press or Joomla. There are 'responsive themes'. And never forget 'media queries' they are essential to create responsive designs. Once you learn media queries your life will be very easy.